# Adding Image to view in swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to add an image to a subview. but whenever I run a simulation I cant see the image while I have label that shows up on the same view

```
 let View:UIView = UIView()
        let CheckImageView:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Checked 1"))
        view.addSubview(View)
        View.backgroundColor = .white
        View.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        View.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor,constant: -20).isActive = true
        View.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        View.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,constant: 0).isActive = true
        View.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        View.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        View.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.15
        View.layer.shadowRadius = 20
        View.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
        View.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        View.addSubview(CheckImageView)
        CheckImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        CheckImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: CheckImageView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        CheckImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: View.topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
        CheckImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: View.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        CheckImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your image size is smaller than expected.

Try to change your image width Anchor

```
CheckImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

[image: This is how my demo image look]